# Change date formatting for database print

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am printing `<?= $order['date'] ?>` on my eCommerce page from a table in my database for products, but it's coming up looking like Y,m,d (for example, 2015-08-30).

I have a Helper class defined as...

```
public static function setDate($case = null, $date = null) {

    $date = empty($date) ? time() : strtotime($date);

    switch ($case) {
        case 1:
        // Example - 01/12/2015
            return date('d/m/Y', $date);
            break;

        case 2:
        // Example - Monday, 1st January 2015, 09:30:45
            return date('l, jS F Y, H:i:s', $date);
            break;

        case 3:
        // Example - 2015-12-01-09-30-45
            return date('Y-m-d-H-i-s', $date);
            break;

        default:
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);      
    }
}
```

How do I use this to format the date as d,m,Y and get my database print looking correct/as I wish (30-08-2015)?

Is it something like `Helper::setdate('$order')` ?  I don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps if you spelt the function right it would help

Comment: I just tried the Helper function but it just shows the current date/time in this format (2015-08-29 23:10:55) and not that as in my database - i.e. the purchase date, and how I'd like it formatted.

Comment: that's the default as shown above `default:
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you've posted has two arguments, a case (format type as shown in the switch statement) and date. You want case (format) 1.

To use it correctly you'd do `Helper::setDate( 1, $date );` replacing `$date` with the correct date variable.

If you need dashes instead of slashes you'd need to add a 4th case to your switch statement:

```
. . .
case 3:
    // Example - 2015-12-01-09-30-45
    return date( 'Y-m-d-H-i-s', $date );
    break;

case 4:
    // Example - 30-08-2015
    return date( 'd-m-Y', $date );
    break;
. . .
```

Comment: sure, just give ashley the fish

Comment: @Dagon Hahaha true! :) I probably went a little bit easy

Comment: Thanks Nathan, just tried this but it's for some reason printing 01/01/1970 when I change $date to 'date', which is the variable I originally used for $order (correct?).

Comment: The purchase date in my MySQL database is 2015-08-07.

Comment: 'date' isn't a date. It's a word; not a variable. You need to pass in a date variable and not the word date. In your case `$order['date']`

Comment: I'm not sure how to get that from the database, sorry.  I have a foreach statement <?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>, so was originally just passing $order and date as writ.  Thanks for the help, just not sure what to change.  Cheers... need more fish :oP

Comment: @AshleySmith Please see revised comment. You have the correct variable in your original question. Just pass that in to the helper method and you're all set.